# node throw error when use async/await syntax.but it works well with import/export syntax

Tags: node.js, babeljs

nodemon throw the error when use async/await syntax:

```
**/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:17
export default function _asyncToGenerator(fn) {
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

but it works well with import/export syntax.

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node server/index.js",
  }
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

asyncToGenerator.js

```
function asyncGeneratorStep(...) { ... }
export default function _asyncToGenerator(fn) {
  return function () {
    var self = this,
        args = arguments;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var gen = fn.apply(self, args);

      function _next(value) {
        asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "next", value);
      }

      function _throw(err) {
        asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "throw", err);
      }

      _next(undefined);
    });
  };
}
```

But I think it probably goes wrong because of my babel setting.

BTW, when I use typeof, it throws the same error

```
**/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/typeof.js:3
export default function _typeof(obj) {
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

update 6/12, 2020:

structure:

```
src (vue app)
server (express app)
  |---- src
  |---- babel.config.js
  |---- index.js
package.json
babel.config.js
```

In this project, I have two babel config, one is for the vue's app, and another is for the express. What I want is running these apps at the project's root path.

And in the beginning, my script about running express is

```
nodemon --exec babel-node server/index.js
```

It can run express, but it gets the wrong babel config(project/babel.config.js)

And the solution is just to point out the specific path which babel confg you want to use(project/server/babel.config.js). So the correct script to run the express is

```
nodemon --exec babel-node --config-file ./server/babel.config.js server/index.js",
```

Comment: Can you please post full script of `asyncToGenerator.js`? async/await is not related to import/export

Comment: @SanSolo  plz check it.

Comment: any solution to this yet?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329589/babel-nodejs-es6-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export

Comment: I don't think you can do export default in node.js

Comment: I can't get the same error. Could please provide us a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

answering [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62316769/6569950):

nodemon doesn't know about babelrc (and it shouldn't). And babel (AFAIK) doesn't allow you to select the babelrc file that you want to use. 
I think that you should merge your babelrc files and set the env flag when running babel-node. Like this: [babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babelrc#env-option](http://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babelrc#env-option)

Another option would be to make a script that renames the babelrc file each time the app is reloaded, or something like that (I don't understand why you need 2 .babelrc files)

Comment: I have added some information about the question. It explains why I need two babel config.In essence, it can split into two project. So I can't merge my babel config.I choose to use babel-node to run my app, and it offers an option called "--config-file".

Answer (score 0):

I read that there are more `.babelrc` files in the project.

From [babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#subpackage-babelrcjson-files) it seems that the `.babelrc` needs to be in the same directory of the subpackage.

Comment: I have added some information abount the question.And because of I use [babel-node](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-node.html) to run my app, it offers me a option called "--config-file", I can put  babel config wherever I want.

Comment: From the doc I understood that `--config-file` is to specify `babel.conf.json` location while `.babelrc` can only be located in the submodule directory.